# Database - how to create regions in TSQL (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to create collapsable regions in the SQL script file like we create in VS using 
`#region ..... #endregion` ?

--EDIT--

Script file contains DDL statements like Alter Table and Alter View etc. and i want to group them in regions like "Table Related Statements" "View Related Statements" etc.

Comment: Regions are Bad, m'OK?!?

Comment: Because hiding information defeats the purpose of having understandable, readable code. Break out into aptly named stored procs...

Comment: its not that i am encrypting the statements. I am just grouping them so that if someone doesnt want to read, can just press F5 and get things done.

Comment: that's the point! the code should always be readable , not tucked away where it might be hiding something, like a bug....

Comment: Disagreed. It can be a stand-alone file where SPs are not available. It may include some code snippets to work on a specific DB, and it may contain some parts with dozens of insert/update/delete entries. There is nothing bad collapsing routine parts to increase readability, so you can see the big picture at a glance. It's like the ability to collapse procedures on most IDEs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, with [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=9)

> **Regions and Debug sections**
>
> Regions behave in the same way as in Visual Studio. You can collapse them and expand them. Debug sections are sections that get commented when you change your script to Release configuration. A debug section is also a collapsable region. If you deploy a script in debug mode with added debug sections it will fail when run from SSMS without SSMS Tools Pack installed. You can of course comment those sections yourself by simply searching for start and end text of the debug sections

Comment: Ah - that's a nice looking utility. Wonder is MS will put some of this stuff in the next version.

Comment: I resisted mentioning that SSMS tools pack supports this: I wish it didn't!!

Answer (score 17):

No, but you can simulate it in SSMS by using `begin..end` blocks as follows:

```
--Region 1
begin
  --Do Something
end

--Region 2
begin 
  --Do Something Else
end
```

The `begin..end` pair is collapsible.

EDIT:

This only works for DML scripts. DDL scripts are more picky as many statements require to be the first in the batch (original question did not state DDL use.)

I don't think there's a way to do this within one script file for DDL - you're into breaking down the script into smaller scripts or stored procs.

Comment: doesnt work as intended. If i have some alter table statements and some alter view statements, script file throws errors saying "ALER must be the only statement in the batch". I want to group my statements with type like "Alter Table statements" "Alter View statements" etc....

Comment: @asdfg. Well now you tell me you're using DDL! - This works for DML, but DDL is more picky as you say.

Comment: sorry. my bad. i should have been little more explicit in declaring the content of the script file. Will update the question.

Comment: see my answer: you can with an SSMS add in

Answer (score 4):

I have added regions support into my add-in [SSMSBoost](http://www.ssmsboost.com) (starting from v 2.12)

Syntax:

```
--#region [OptionalName]

--#endregion
```

Answer (score 3):

to respond to the "Alter must be the only statement in the batch" error, you may "seperate" your Begin and End batches with the GO command, that way you'd avoid this message, like so:

```
begin 
--do something
end
GO

begin
--do something else
end
GO
```

and so forth